# ExtJS 7 Force Froala editor to fit parent component size

Tags: extjs, froala

Is it possible to configure Froala editor so that it always matches the size of the parent component in height and width?

Currently it goes beyond the boundaries of the parent component as the amount of text increases, not matter what layout I am using.

I have checked the list of available options and examples, but did not find an appropriate settings. The only option I can use now is explicitly set height and width for a [Ext.froala.Mixin.editor](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/modern/Ext.froala.Mixin.html#cfg-editor) config.

I am using ExtJS 7.2, modern toolkit.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/36be&view/editor)

I expect a scroll inside a Froala editor component, but instead a Froala editor component exceed height of the parent component.

Comment: Please create a fiddle with your problem. I tried to reproduce your problem based on an example from the documentation and I didn’t succeed. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/36b8&view/editor

Comment: @pvlt Just set fixed height for a parent component and try to add text into froala editor that overflows its height - I expect scroll inside froala editor component, but instead froala editor exceed height of parent component. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/36be&view/editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `overflow: auto;` for flora wrapper:

```
    .fr-box.fr-basic.fr-top .fr-wrapper {
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/36bf&view/editor)

Comment: Thanks, works. Sad, that costly Ext JS doesn't have this functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE for extjs v7.5.0, froala v4.0.8:

```
.x-froala .fr-wrapper {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 0px;
}
```